# What is the name of the expression $(^)(^)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, inverse, transpose

I'm told this expression $(^)(^)^{-1}$ has a name and I suppose, has a use.

What is the name of it?

Comment: The name is *identity*: $(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}=I$.

Comment: In other words, it's the same definition for Identity, regardless of whether $(Y)(Y)^{-1}$, Y in this case being $(X^{T}X)$  or something else. - Correct?

Comment: You could add meaningful context to avoid your question being closed. Where were you told this expression has a name? Did you find it in a paper or somewhere?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $Y=X^TX$ is invertible, then clearly
$$
(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}=YY^{-1}=I
$$
is the identity matrix.

You might refer instead to $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, which is a particular left inverse of $X$, because
$$
\bigl((X^TX)^{-1}X^T\bigr)X=(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)=I
$$
This has a name: it is the [*Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $X$ (it's a very particular case). Proving the properties that show it is indeed the pseudoinverse is easy.